# Dashboard UI is not accessible

Tags: kubernetes

Dashboard UI not working. I'm trying to troubleshoot kubernetes UI Dashboard. It is not working so far. I have a cluster with three nodes, 1 master and 2 workers

```
Error: 'dial tcp 172.16.1.4:8443: i/o timeout' Trying to reach: 'https://172.16.1.4:8443/'
Error: 'dial tcp 172.16.1.4:8443: i/o timeout' Trying to reach: 'https://172.16.1.4:8443/'
```

The issue is that when the proxy is activated, the Dashboard does not display on the worker machine (node1) which is the one where dashboard is running

I'm trying to troubleshoot kubernetes UI Dashboard. It is not working so far. I have a cluster with three nodes, 1 master and 2 workers:

```
[admin@k8s-node1 ~]$ kubectl get nodes 
NAME STATUS ROLES AGE VERSION 
k8s-master Ready master 4d21h v1.15.2 
k8s-node1 Ready 4d20h v1.15.2 
k8s-node2 Ready 4d20h v1.15.2
```

```
[admin@k8s-node1 ~]$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE NAME READY STATUS RESTARTS AGE IP NODE NOMINATED NODE READINESS GATES
kube-system coredns-5c98db65d4-7fztc 1/1 Running 2 4d20h 172.16.0.5 k8s-master kube-system coredns-5c98db65d4-wwb4t 1/1 Running 2 4d20h 172.16.0.4 k8s-master kube-system etcd-k8s-master 1/1 Running 1 4d20h 10.1.99.10 k8s-master 
kube-system kube-apiserver-k8s-master 1/1 Running 1 4d20h 10.1.99.10 k8s-master 
kube-system kube-controller-manager-k8s-master 1/1 Running 1 4d20h 10.1.99.10 k8s-master 
kube-system kube-router-bt2rb 1/1 Running 0 30m 10.1.99.11 k8s-node1 
kube-system kube-router-dnft9 1/1 Running 0 30m 10.1.99.10 k8s-master 
kube-system kube-router-z98ns 1/1 Running 0 29m 10.1.99.12 k8s-node2 
kube-system kube-scheduler-k8s-master 1/1 Running 1 4d20h 10.1.99.10 k8s-master 
kubernetes-dashboard kubernetes-dashboard-5c8f9556c4-8skmv 1/1 Running 0 43m 172.16.1.4 k8s-node1 
kubernetes-dashboard kubernetes-metrics-scraper-86456cdd8f-htq9t 1/1 Running 0 43m 172.16.2.7 k8s-node2
```

URL: http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

The Log for the Dashboard deployment shows the following message:

```
Metric client health check failed: the server is currently unable to handle the request (get services dashboard-metrics-scraper). Retrying in 30 seconds.
```

Expect for the Dashboard UI to load with URL, but get error message instead.

Comment: Where the error you've quoted comes from and where exactly do you see it:
`Error: 'dial tcp 172.16.1.4:8443: i/o timeout' Trying to reach: 'https://172.16.1.4:8443/` ?

Comment: from the web browser after I attempt to access the Dashboard UI

Comment: Is Dashboard accessible from the k8s-master or k8s-node1 command prompt with curl: `curl -k https://<clusterIP>:443` or `curl -k https://172.16.1.4:8443`  ? Could you provide output of the command `kubectl get services kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system -o yaml` ? There is similar discussion at (https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/3789)

Comment: The Dashboard is not accessible from any host (master, node1 or node2). It currently is running on k8s-node2. I have tried to remove/install without any luck. I also tried changing the configuration from ClusterIP to Node but despite this, the issue remains. Here's the output of commands you proposed:

[admin@k8s-master ~]$ curl -k https://10.40.0.1:443
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.40.0.1:443; No route to host
[admin@k8s-master ~]$

Comment: [admin@k8s-master ~]$ kubectl get services kubernetes-dashboard -n kube-system -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"k8s-app":"kubernetes-dashboard"},"name":"kubernetes-dashboard","namespace":"kube-system"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":443,"targetPort":8443}],"selector":{"k8s-app":"kubernetes-dashboard"}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2019-08-16T16:36:21Z"

Comment: labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "128884"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
  uid: d44a7f5b-b2bd-4a7f-b0f6-14756053bb5f
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.103.161.122
  ports:
  - port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}

Comment: Since you use proxy, you should go via proxy, not directly to the pod or node IP. When you enter `kubectl proxy &`, it responds "Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001" and gets ready. Since then you might enter for instance `curl -k 127.0.0.1:8001/api1` to ensure kube-api responds to you.

Comment: Yes, the error is being reported on the proxy (http://127.0.0.1:8001) connection. If you look at the URL on my original message, I am actually attempting to connect to proxy (localhost) on port 8001. The error message however shows the IP address of the node running the service.

Comment: api1 responds successfully. Dashboard fails as stated originally
curl -k 127.0.0.1:8001/api1
{
  "paths": [
    "/apis",
    "/apis/",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io",
    "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1",
    "/healthz",
    "/healthz/etcd",
    "/healthz/log",
    "/healthz/ping",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/crd-informer-synced",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers",
    "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers",
    "/metrics",
    "/openapi/v2",
    "/version"
  ]
}

Comment: Please note that Dashboard is installed into the non-standard namespace "kubernetes-dashboard". That is not supported, and users are facing issues: [#1691](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/1691), [#3566](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/3566). It makes sense to re-install Dashboard in the standard way into the kube-system namespace, w/o the third-party package managers like Helm, and then check how it works. Apart from kubernetes.io and Github, you may follow straightforward steps from here: https://kubernetestutorials.com/how-to-install-kubernetes-dashboard/

Comment: `kubectl get services` gives ClusterIP=10.103.161.122. Why do you enter ` curl -k 10.40.0.1:443` then? There is nothing listening on that address.